# Passing data between routes with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Suppose I am currently on the page 'A' with a inputfield.
I enter "123" in the inputfield and navigate to page 'B'.
(I don't need the value '123' on Page B). But when I navigate from 'B' back to page 'A' I want the previusly entered value '123' is still in the inputfield.
Is there a build in options in Anuglar to do this without passing the value through the route:id like 'pageb/123' and without storing it in the localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use services, for store some variable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService{
    public myVar = '';

    constructor(){}
}
```

then add this service in **provider** of **app.module.ts**

Now you can use this service in your components.

```
import { MyService } from '...';

export class AComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: MyService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.myService.myVar = 'something';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a service. There is no other way because when you navigate away your component instance is destroyed. If you navigate back a new instance of that component is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngrx/store of you have extensive number of these kinda cases, following is the link
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md